# Deleting objects via ajax in rails 3.1rc4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails 3.1 app and i cant seem to delete my images via ajax. my code smaple is

```
def destroy
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  @photo.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(user_photos_path(current_user)) }
    format.js   { render :nothing => true }
  end
end
```

then in my views i have

```
<%= link_to '(delete)', profile_photo_path(photo.profile, photo), :method => :delete if me %>
```

in my application.js i have

```
$('.delete_post').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
```

it does not work for me. it performs the action but it does not fade out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax:success callback `this` is not bound to the .delete_post link as you expect it to be.  Maybe you could add IDs to your links, then in your controller or template generate some javascript like `$("#photo_17_delete").closest('tr').fadeOut();`.  That's just an example of one way to handle it.

Comment: Just found out that the problem is from that rails version.. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I just wanted to point out that it seems like it's a bad practice to use links to actions that modify or destroy your data.

You should be using to_button instead

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: yea thanks for the tip.. But i just feel button_to is difficult to customize.